# Undefined variable while uploading a file in php

Tags: php, html, string

i am trying to store 2 images in my database . when i upload 2 images then both are storing successfully but when in try to upload single image then its giving undefined error for un-uploaded  image. where i am wrong ?

My code is:

```
         <label for="certificate">Upload Scaned Document:</label>
         <input type="file" id="uploadImage" name="image" />
         <label for="certificate">Upload Scaned QR Code</label>
         <input type="file" name="QRimage" id="File2" />
```

And php code is

```
if((!empty($_FILES["image"])) && ($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0))   {
    $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
    $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);

}
if((!empty($_FILES["QRimage"])) && ($_FILES['QRimage']['error'] == 0)) {
    $QRimageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["QRimage"]["name"]);
    $QRimageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["QRimage"]["tmp_name"])); 
}
```

Comment: @RakeshSharma OP says when upload two image it working fine that means no need to check `enctype`.

Comment: can you show your upload code

Comment: i am uploading the file using html form . input type="file" @Sharma Vikram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$imageName = "";
$imageData = "";
$QRimageName = "";
$QRimageData = "";
if(!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])){ 
 $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
 $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
 }
 if(!empty($_FILES["QRimage"]["name"])){
 $QRimageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["QRimage"]["name"]);
  $QRimageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["QRimage"]["tmp_name"]));
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add check of **isset** for both **if** condition..because when you are uploading both images then $_FILES getting image and its giving true in if condition but when uploading one image then other image if case not getting image in $_FILES so its giving error of undefined...variable should set before any operation..

```
if(isset($_FILES["image"]) && (!empty($_FILES["image"])) && ($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0))   {

if(isset($_FILES["QRimage"]) && (!empty($_FILES[" QRimage "])) && ($_FILES[' QRimage ']['error'] == 0))   {
```

Comment: new error (Undefined variable: QRimageName) and (QRimageData)

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: QRimageName in C:\wamp\www\print\main.php on line 56

Answer (score 1):

Check with [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) like

```
if((isset($_FILES["image"]["size"]) && 
    ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 0))
 {
 }

if((isset($_FILES["QRimage"]["size"]) && 
    ($_FILES["QRimage"]["size"] > 0))
{
   $QRimageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["QRimage"]["name"]);     
   $QRimageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["QRimage"]["tmp_name"]));
}
```

Comment: new error (Undefined variable: QRimageName) and (QRimageData)

Comment: The problem is you set the variables inside a conditional statement. If that conditional statement doesn't pass then those variables essentially dont exist within the application for use later on. Try initializing the `QRimageName` variable before the if statements.

Comment: where are you used variable `QRimageName` and `QRimageData`?

Comment: then the error is (Warning: file_get_contents() [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: Filename cannot be empty )

Comment: Your warning message display `<a>` tag with `function.file-get-contents`.

Comment: i dont know . what i have posted that is my code . what next ?

Comment: In which line are you getting warning can you show this code?

Comment: when i used your solution and uploaded only one image then its give error that undefined variables ($QRimageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["QRimage"]["name"]);
    $QRimageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["QRimage"]["tmp_name"])); )

Comment: if i remove that then i will get this error ((Warning: file_get_contents() [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: Filename cannot be empty ))

Comment: Check my updated answer and implement in your code same as mentioned in answer

Comment: i used same code . when i upload [image] image then [QRimage] image is undefining  . when upload [QRimge] then [image] in undefining .